# the edge is visible in object mode

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

[image]

I created the edge using curves then converting into mesh and somehow the edge isn't disappearing at all when I exit edit mode. removed doubles

Comment: could you show us screenshots of your outliner window?

Comment: This is usually the result of having two overlapping edges, either within the same object, or in different objects. Make sure your original curve object isn't still there, overlapping with the mesh. Go into edit mode within the mesh, and make sure you don't have two overlapping edges there either. If you upload the file, we could tell you for sure.